# What are the generic terms for HTTP Pipelines and HTTP Modules, which seem to be .Net-specific terminology

Tags: http, webserver, terminology

In .Net, a web server processes an HTTP Request or HTTP Response, by sending it through an HTTP Pipeline that's made up of HTTP Modules, where each module can manipulate the request or response.

I drew a diagram at work that used this terminology, where .Net is not used, and people didn't know what I was talking about until I explained the concepts generically.

But I still don't know what specific terms I should use outside of a .Net environment.

So, in other languages, like Python, Go, Node, C++, etc., or generically, what are HTTP Pipelines and HTTP Modules called?